# Redirect one process stdout to pipe will make difference running result?

Tags: c++, process, pipe, poco

```
    Poco::Pipe outputPipe;
    Poco::Pipe errorPipe;
    Poco::Process::Env env;
    Poco::Process::Args arg;
    Poco::Process::launch(exeFile, arg, workDir, 0 , &outputPipe, &errorPipe, env);
```

I use the above code to create two processes, one is right, the other is wrong. Then I change the code

```
    Poco::Process::launch(exeFile, arg, workDir, 0 , 0, 0, env);
```

The only difference is I don't redirect the stdout and stderr to pipes. Then I create two processes, now it's all right.

In my opinion, I dont't think Redirecting the stdout and stderr will cause process running with different results. Is it right?

If i am wrong, what situation will make the difference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways that the change can make a difference:

1. You don't show the code that reads the pipes. If one of the pipes fills before the reading code reads the data, the launched process will block writing to the pipe until the data is read from the pipe.
2. When the output (in particular) is a pipe, the output is likely to be fully buffered rather than line buffered or unbuffered.  This can mean that output doesn't appear as swiftly as in the unpiped example.  Your program might write a line, and then do some work, and then write another line, but neither of those is necessarily sent to the process reading the pipe (unless the application flushes the output, or sets line-buffered output mode).

Comment: You're right. My code that reads the pipes is wrong, so pipe fills and the launched process  block.  Thanks